# Cardinality of mappings, finding which is greater

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I was asked: [image: Cardinality of mappings, which is unlike the others?]

I believe it is B because the cardinality of the reals is greater and there is no power set here, but someone is telling me that it's A. Can someone explain why I'm wrong or right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The five sets (a) through (e) have cardinality $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$, $2^{\aleph_0}$, $(2^{\aleph_0})^{100}$, $2^{\aleph_0}$ and... something... respectively. The first four of these are all equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$, so the answer is likely to be (e).

And, indeed, (e) is countable. Here's a proof. Let $E$ be the set of solutions to polynomial equations with integral coefficients. Each element of $E$ can be determined by specifying a tuple of the form $(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n,i)$, where $n \ge 1$, $a_k \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $0 \le k \le n$, and $i \ge 1$. Namely, the tuple $(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n,i)$ corresponds to the $i^{\text{th}}$-least solution to the polynomial equation $a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n$ (there are fewer than $i$ solutions, just take the greatest solution). This establishes a surjection
$$\bigcup_{n \ge 1} \mathbb{Z}^{n+1} \times \mathbb{N}^{\ge 1} \to E$$
and since the domain is a countable union of a countable product of countable sets, it is countable, so that $E$ is countable too.